# How to make my library project on GitHub importable via Gradle?

Tags: android, github, gradle, android-studio

Is there a way to make my library project I host on GitHub to be linked in Android Studio in my new project, so I can easily update linked version to the remote version?

Basically I have project A - stored on GitHub.
I want to link project A in project B, so every time project A changes it will be updated in project B also.

Comment: What do you mean by 'hosted' and 'stored' on github? Are you publishing binary releases on github? If so, are you using 'github releases'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way I know how to do this is to host it on your own Maven reposiotory - this might help- (http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-include-library-manully-into-maven-local-repository/), or Maven Central. Then in your build.gradle file reference it:

```
compile 'com.example.app:library:+'
```

Where the '+' is always checking for the newest version (My syntax might be off as well)

The only issue then is running a git pull too often, but you could always create a bash script that gets called every so often, then that should do the trick as well.

Comment: This answer is a little outdated, since Android moving forward prefers jcenter to mavenCentral from what I've seen. I should update the answer but don't have the time currently.